# How call async method from non async web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I am having web api, which is non async.

From that web api, i am calling method

SmtpClient.SendMailAsync(email);

This email get sent to respective person, but the next web api request get fails.

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public TestController(TestService testService)
    {
       _testService = testService;
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Post(data)
     {
         _testService.SendEmail(data);
     }
}

public class TestService 
{
    public async Task SendEmail(MailMessage email)
     {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.SendMailAsync(email)
     }
}
```

Comment: Usually there is still a non-Async Method. In this case, SendMail rather then SendMailAsync.

Comment: replace `_testService.SendEmail(data);` with `_testService.SendEmail(data).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`

Comment: @ravikumar: I don't want to wait till email sent, i want behavior like fire and forget.

Comment: @HemantMalpote: note, that `SmtpClient` must be disposed. Wrap it into `using`.

Comment: @Dennis : agree

Comment: @Dennis: Issue is still present, didn't works.

Comment: @HemantMalpote: what issue? what exactly means "didn't works"?

Comment: *"next web api request get fails"* - Can you expand on this? Which GET request is failing? How does it fail?

Answer (score 1):

From the days before the async/await pattern was introduced, there are still many non-asychronous functions around in Framework classes.

SmtpClient client is one of the classes old enough for this. The SendFunction are the droids you are look for:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.send

While the naming is a bit off and they return void, those seems to be the pre-async functions. Failure should be communicated via Exceptions in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Given your comment that you want to have SendEmail behave like fire & forget, I would propose using

```
Task.Run(() => _testService.SendEmail(data));
```

This will give the unit of work to the threadpool and free your request from the duty of waiting for this task. Generelly this is advised for fire & forget.

As a rule of thumb otherwise, it's generally a bad idea to call asynchronous things from a synchronous context. Do async all the way, or be prepared for deadlocking. For example, you could simply make your controller actions asynchronous as well.

Comment: In this particular case it's OK to call some async stuff in fire-and-forget way from  synchronous code.

Answer (score 0):

If you will need use some result of sending:

```
    public async IHttpActionResult Post(data)
 {
     var t = Task.Run(() =>_testService.SendEmail(data));

     var result = await t;
     // do something with result
 }
```

- but of course your SendEmail function should return `Task<>` instead of `Task` ...